# Unable to save file to local storage in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios7

I am trying to download file content from server, creating one file on client end and tranfering all content to that. I am saving the file to local storage,but it is unable to save throws exception that you don't have permission to save in folder. Tried so many things but unable to do so. I am very new to this ios programming. Please help me out, thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
 let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
 var fileURL : URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsUrl!.path+filename)
  fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsUrl!.path+filename+".doc")
  let data = NSData(contentsOf: tempLocalUrl)
                do {
                    try data?.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                } catch {
                    print(error,"helooooooooooooooooo")
                }
```

I have used relativepath, absolutestring but still no luck .

This is the error :

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “DocumentsImport From IE.doc” in the folder “0103E60B-478F-475B-A8F2-788534F5D206”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0103E60B-478F-475B-A8F2-788534F5D206/DocumentsImport From IE.doc, NSUnderlyingError=0x1076efe90 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

Comment: where is the `documentsUrl` coming from? how did you extract that URL?

Comment: I have edited code, please check @holex

Comment: and I'm sure you have spotted the missing `/` between the path and filename... like `.../Documents` + `/` + `Import From IE.doc`, you currently don't have the `/` – it is better to use the [`addPathComponent(...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780397-appendpathcomponent) rather than concatenating the raw string values... that may help you to avoid such glitches in future.

Comment: Never concatenate strings to build paths. Use the appropriate API of URL. This solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks @holex it works, you saved my time.

Comment: Thanks @vadian i got your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Save my image like that

```
 let fileManager = FileManager.default
 do {

     let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
     let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
     let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Notifications")if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {
         try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
         return true  
     }
 } catch {   
    print(error) 
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

Never build paths like

```
documentsUrl!.path+filename+".doc"
```

**Don't do that.** You could forget the path separators which you actually did.

URL provides dedicated APIs to build paths

```
let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(filename).appendingPathExtension("doc")
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: tempLocalUrl) // not NSData !!
    try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
} catch {
    print(error,"helooooooooooooooooo")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your path in the error is:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0103E60B-478F-475B-A8F2-788534F5D206/DocumentsImport From IE.doc
```

instead of:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0103E60B-478F-475B-A8F2-788534F5D206/Documents/Import From IE.doc
```

And use [appendingPathComponent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1410614-appendingpathcomponent) to concatenate path elements.